# What is an acyclic connected graph in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory

I want to know What it is and whether there is a difference in the definition when looking at undirected and directed graphs?

Comment: In undirected, it is a tree. Definitely more complicated when directed.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What is a tree?

Comment: It's the name for an undirected connected acyclic graph.

Comment: @Jnyeboah93 check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of stating the obvious...

To create a graph, you start with a set of nodes (or vertices). These are essentially points in space - a bunch of dots. Then you add a set of arcs (or edges). An arc is a line that joins one node to another. Arcs can be directed (in which case you can only travel in one direction along them) or undirected.

A connected graph is defined as a graph where you can get from any one node to any other node by travelling along some arcs (possibly via many other nodes).

A cycle is a set of arcs that will take you from one starting node to some other nodes and back to the starting node without ever travelling along the same arc twice. It's a loop, if you like.

An acyclic graph has no cycles.